# ActiveX as bridge beween .Net Desktop application and Browser

Tags: .net, activex

I want to communicate between a browser-based application and a .Net based desktop application. Can I use ActiveX as a bridge for the communication? I created an ActiveX control and I can access it from the browser. How do I get access to the same ActiveX instance from the desktop application? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want the .NET application to start as a standalone EXE and grab a reference to the ActiveX object hosted in the browser? I don't think browsers expose access to the ActiveX controls they host (not to mention there can be several instances of a browser, and therefore several instances of the ActiveX control).

What you **can** do is turn the .NET application into a DLL, which gets loaded by the ActiveX control.